# xml2csv with python / BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to convert an XML file to CSV, I tried around a bit with BeautifulSoup, but my Python knowledge is almost non-existent. I tired a bit, but that's far as I got.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# infile = open("test.xml","r")
# data = infile.read()
data = """<ROOT>
<SUB1>
  <credential id='3' name='somename' host='somehost' username='someusername' info='someinfo' type='LDAP' opSys='' url='3423' email='33454'>
    <notes />
    <label id='1' />
  </credential>
<credential id='3' name='somename2' host='somehost2' username='someusername2' info='someinfo2' type='LDAP' opSys='' url='12' email='34'>
    <notes>some note
asdasdasd </notes>
      <label id='4' />
    </credential>
  </SUB1>
</ROOT>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'xml')

# export as csv, should look like this
# name;host;username;info;type;url;email;notes;label
# "somename";"somehost";"someusername";"someinfo";LDAP;"3423;"33454";"";1
# "somenane2";"somehost2";"someusername2";"someinfo2";LDAP;"12";"34";"somenote asdasdasd";4


print("name;host;username;info;type;url;email;notes;label")



notes = soup.find_all('notes')
for notes in notes:
    if notes == "":
        print("")
    else:
        notes = notes.get_text('\n', '')
        print(notes)
```

Could someone give a few hints?

Comment: As each row of your output CSV corresponds to a credential, you'll need to structure your code to iterate over those. I'd also recommend you do a bit more reading on how to use BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to return all the element you want at the same time. You could then determine which one is being returned using `elem.name` and build up the necessary information for each row. As `label` comes last, you could use that to write the output row.

Python has a [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#module-csv) to help you with this. It takes a list of values and correctly formats it as an output row. Normally you would not need to add quotes to everything, but as your expected output has this, you can add `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` to force it to add it to all values.

[`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) is just a useful function that can extract the require elements from Python data, e.g. a list or a dictionary in a single call.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from operator import itemgetter
import csv

credential_fields = ['name', 'host', 'username', 'info', 'type', 'url', 'email']
get_fields = itemgetter(*credential_fields)

with open('test.xml') as f_input:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_input, 'xml')

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    csv_output.writerow(credential_fields + ['notes', 'label'])

    for elem in soup.find_all(['notes', 'credential', 'label']):
        if elem.name == 'notes':
            note = elem.get_text(strip=True).replace('\n', ' ')
        elif elem.name == 'credential':
            credential = list(get_fields(elem))
        else:
            label = elem['id']
            csv_output.writerow(credential + [note, label])
```

This would give you an output format:

```
"name";"host";"username";"info";"type";"url";"email";"notes";"label"
"somename";"somehost";"someusername";"someinfo";"LDAP";"3423";"33454";"";"1"
"somename2";"somehost2";"someusername2";"someinfo2";"LDAP";"12";"34";"some noteasdasdasd";"4"
```

Comment: I added "sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')" and removed newline='' and then it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are using Python 2.x